# I want to quit badly but cannot find something else

Tags: job-search, new-job, resignation

I'm 25, i graduated from university about 6 months ago, i've been in the industry for 2-3 years. **I joined a small company a few months ago and already want to quit.** I dread going to work every day, mostly because the project i'm in is dead boring and I feel like I'm unlearning every good practice I know of. I feel completely demotivated, and all the alarms have gone off in my head that if I don't leave soon it will reflect in my perf review. My teammates hate the project too, I hear nothing but complaints.

However, **i've been rejected in two out of the three places I've applied.** The first one rejected me without a reason, but I know HR lied to me at one point so I think I dodged a bullet. The other company (top notch) told me I lacked technical skills but suggested that I reapply in the future because they liked me. I honestly thought I had done well and was confident I would get the job. The rejection hit me hard and this is why I'm posting here.

My only hope is with the other place. I'm pretty sure I won't get this job either because I lack knowledge of the business. The interviewer told me that he realized this but he saw enthusiasm in me so we are moving forward. I was referred from an employee so that may help a bit.

At this point, I see three options:

1. Cross fingers that I will be accepted and just leave current
   employer
2. Leave current employer and keep looking (what will the
   interviewers think of me when I say that I am unemployed?)
3. Stay at current employer and keep looking (I won't stand much
   longer here)

**So my question is... what do I do? Suck it up or leave employer and hope something comes along?**

This is putting me down to the point that I feel that my degree hasn't been enough, so I'm considering enrolling into online courses (Coursera, MIT, etc.). But it will be weeks/months until I get something out of them. It's not like I haven't been studying though, I read a lot and watch Pluralsight courses.... I'm just lost here.

Comment: Looking for a new job is a matter of patience. As long as you have a paying job, you're in position of force. If you leave your current job, you'll be helpless, OTOH, and vulnerable. Something potential employers usually don't like.

Comment: "The rejection hit me hard and this is why I'm posting here" - Try not to let the given rejection reason affect you too personally. After all, they could have just said something generic like "we decided not to continue with your application". A generic reason like this might not "hit you hard" but it also doesn't offer you any insight into their decision process.

Comment: Apply to many jobs, three is not enough to be discouraged about, it may take a hundred or more applications to find the one you want. And be picky about it it as well. You are currently employed, so take the time to find a job that will be better not just different.

Comment: So are you saying that your first job out of college is boring and they don't operate the way you were taught in school? Consider this Business Education 301: the way you were taught in school barely counts in the real world; work will often be boring and it is up to you to find excitement and joy in what you do; and it is up to you to find solutions to your problems. If you don't get a passing grade in BE301, you will have the opportunity to retake it until you do. The solutions you listed will result in a Fail or Barely Passed. Best of luck! :)

Comment: @BryanH: this is not my first job.

Comment: @gazzz0x2z: it is true, but money doesn't matter to me right now. I have savings. My mental health is more important...

Answer (score 15):

Don't leave your job without another lined up unless something very extreme is happening at your current job, for example, they are asking you to do something illegal, or they are abusive to their employees.  Yes, it's horribly frustrating to be trapped in a job you hate, but it's even worse to be unemployed with no end in sight, and worried about your bills. And at least while you're employed, your frustration isn't for nothing, because you're adding experience to your resume.  Even if you don't think it's good experience, it will make your resume more attractive to employers.

Comment: Thaks Kai, but just to clarify. I'm not worried about my bills. I have savings and I live with my parents (long story). I'm worried about my mental health here. I don't feel happy.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to switch companies why do you only have one active application. The key to getting a new job is to apply. You should make a point of submitting a few more applications in the next few days. Then next week do it again.

When I have need to find a job, I juggled multiple waves of applications. I always had a few in each stage of the process. I kept that up until I accepted a new position. Afterwards I withdrew most of the applications, but kept a few active until my first day of work.

Answer (score -4):

I think #1 is your best option, as it will force you to hustle and do whatever it takes to get a better job.  Right now you hate your job, but not enough to hustle and put in 100 applications.

So, if you *really* want to get a different job, put yourself in a position where you have no choice but to do so.

If not, go talk to your manager about this, and let them know what's going on.  He might be able to help, but you'll never know until you talk to them.